# WAR won't deploy on WildFly - no errors

Tags: java, wildfly

I'm trying to get my application's WAR file to deploy on WildFly 13. It deploys fine under Tomcat. I initially ran into a couple of issues around Java EE 7 trying to use CDI and such (which I don't want as it's a Spring application), but I resolved those issues. Now, it just sits there silently for 10 minutes, and gives up:

```
2018-07-13 08:20:01,988 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "myapp.war" (runtime-name: "myapp.war")
2018-07-13 08:30:00,086 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment "myapp.war" was rolled back with no failure message
2018-07-13 08:30:00,087 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0027: Operation was interrupted before service container stability could be reached. Process should be restarted. Step that first updated the service container was 'deploy' at address '[("deployment" => "myapp.war")]'
```

Then, after another 2 minute pause, it spits out a flurry of 'this JAR has a Class-Path reference that's unresolved' messages and says that the WAR is undeployed:

```
2018-07-13 08:32:02,720 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry chartfx.gauge.design.jar in /C:/FDE/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/bin/content/myapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/chartfx.gauge-7.0.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
...
2018-07-13 08:32:05,084 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment myapp.war (runtime-name: myapp.war) in 124998ms
```

For reference, this WAR takes around 2 minutes to deploy on Tomcat. An earlier version has worked just fine on JBoss 7.1 back when that was the current version.

The silent failure mode is the most irritating aspect; any suggestions on how to diagnose this?

Comment: Can you upload the war so someone can try it ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra - I'm afraid not; it's not my code to share.

Comment: I think **chartfx.gauge.design.jar** this jar may required some dependency which may be not compatible with wildfly13, just a guess ?not sure

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra There are many more similar warnings like that; I think they're mainly for optional dependencies we aren't using or for JARs that are named differently, but will be found without issue in the Servlet container context. I never noticed the issue on Tomcat, as it doesn't do this sort of checking. I don't think, but am not certain, that these are related to the problem at hand.

Comment: With your given data it is difficult to help on this, you can try something like enabling the TRACE log for server and then check. just an idea.

Comment: increased deployment timeout should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Extract the war and check all jar files' manifests. It seems some classpath is encoded there that refers to some developer's machine which should not be there.
Or raise a bug report for the developers to fix.